# 18.04, Deja Dup, backup to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: 18.04, backup, deja-dup, aws

18.04 has a nag message about backups.  I tried to [configure it](http://mooooo.ooo/deja-dup-s3-backups/) to [backup to an AWS s3 bucket](http://blog.domenech.org/2013/01/backing-up-ubuntu-using-deja-dup-backup-and-aws-s3.html), as I'd done in 16.04.

The new Deja Dup UI doesn't show AWS S3 as an option in "Online Accounts" 
 (even after installing the packages above).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this GNOME Wiki article](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Clouds), they've removed support for cloud providers by default.

You can re-enable support by,

1. Opening `dconf-editor`.
2. Navigating to `/org/gnome/deja-dup` and changing the value of the `backend` key to `s3`.
3. When you next open Duplicity/Déjà Dup, S3 will now show as the default option.

Comment: One other thing I did in dconf-editor was to set `/org/gnome/deja-dup/s3/bucket` to the bucket name.  This is different than `folder` which is a folder inside the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

They've now completely removed support for S3. If anyone is looking for an alternative to Deja Dup + S3, you can try [Oak Backup](https://www.oakbackup.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do a backup to s3 is to use a library that maps s3 as fs. For example, install and configure s3fs-fuse (https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse), and mount in certain location as you do with an additional disk. Then if you backup over that folder you're going to send up to s3 your backups.